# How to install OpenTok without using composer

Tags: php, webrtc, opentok

I have downloaded PHP SDK from

> https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-PHP-SDK/archive/master.zip

As described [here](https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/server/php/), It says 'Composer' needs to be there to install the SDK. I want to know if is there any different method though which we can just load required classes and run the application? OpenTok is really new to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [basic links](http://example.com).